# addChildInternal SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

I am getting this below error when launching apache tomcat server.

I have re installed the tomcat too. Not able to figure out what would be the thing I am missing. Went through different answers for the similar issues but doesn't seem to work with any of the solutions

```
let Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Oct 02, 2019 11:59:33 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\myapplication\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 02, 2019 12:01:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapplication]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ProcessingException
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2944)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1208)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:400)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
        ... 31 more

Oct 02, 2019 12:01:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\myapplication.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapplication]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The exception is pretty clear... `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException` is quite a give away.

Comment: @M.Deinum which means??

Comment: What do you think a `ClassNotFoundException` means?

Comment: oops Thanks. My bad. I was expecting a solution here. I got a re explanation of my own problem

Comment: I'm trying to make you think of what is wrong, instead of blindly giving you the solution. A class-not-found is pretty clear. You are missing classes in your application. Specifally the JAX-RS classes/dependencies.

Comment: I have all dependencies added but still this is happening servel.jar gets added fine. Not able to get it.. spent a whole day by now :(

Comment: `servlet.jar` doesn't contain `jax-rs` classes. The fact that you have the error means you don't have all the dependencies, else you wouldn't be getting the `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar is also being added

Comment: Not according to the exception.

Comment: Yup it does in project folder when I start to deploy the application. but its not present in the apache tomcat lib folder .. is that the issue? I just pasted to tomcat lib folder to see if it works
Ooops and it worked. But shouldn't that be reading it from my project web-inf/lib/ if it's present there .. why its been searching it tomcat/lib/

Comment: Don't place those things in tomcat/lib. that is a general directory NOT an application dependencies directory. The jar must be in `WEB-INF/lib` so make sure your artifact that gets deployed has them. When using maven make sure it has the correct scope etc. However without knowning how you build your project or just rely on your IDE it is hard to help.